# What is the difference between ехать and поехать

Tags: глаголы

I understand they both mean to go (by vehicle) but I can't get the difference in my head. Can someone provide English examples, please

Comment: "ехать" is about the process of going, while "поехать" (as well as "съездить") is about the destination. We can't use "поехать" in present tense - only in past or future.

Comment: @Alexander that's an answer, not a comment

Comment: This basically asks how perfective verbs differ from imperfective. This has been asked and answered numerous times on this site.